# C++ API DLL Project

Tags: c++, winforms, api, winapi, dll

I have a C++ project which uses an API that comes with DLL and LIB files, as well as a header file.
I want to create a win32 forms project.

My question is how do I link the project with the dll and lib files.

But the main question is, how do I subscribe to events?
In the API I can call functions, which come back as on event response, which in a MFC project I would generally subscribe in the message loop. But in the Win32 there is no message loop.

Maybe I am complicating the situation myself and it is easier than I imagine.
Please clarify this situation for me.

Thank you.

Comment: When you're using the Win32 API directly, it's up to you to create your own message loop.

Comment: How do I do it? And how will I ensure that I get "on event" responses from the functions I am calling from the API?

Comment: Maybe I should back up: are you creating any actual windows in this program, or is it a console program?

Comment: Jerry, my bad, I didn't mention that I intend to use win32 forms project. So, yes, I want to create forms.

Comment: Any specific reason you're going with winforms rather than WPF ? I only ask because winforms' days are somewhat numbered. MS is banking on WPF for the mid-term future (but you can count on them changing even that, as usual).

Answer (score 2):

It's always hard to answer when someone asks more than one question...  In the case of your "main question", please show the relevant API call for subscribing to events.  You are wrong about there being no message loop in Win32...  It's just that there's no *MFC* message loop.

I'm answering the easy question for now...  "how do you link the DLL".  I am kinda assuming you are using Visual Studio.  Is that correct?  The way I do this, when I'm in a hurry is like so:

```
#include "mylib.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")
```

That's all there is to it.  Of course I want the header, but while I'm at it I tell the compiler to link the library too.

I seem to recall other times where I simply dragged the library file into the project's solution view, effectively adding it as a source.  That also works.

The long way is to edit your project settings, go to the **Linker** section, and under the **Input** subsection, you add your library to the **Additional Dependencies** list.  You need to do that for all configurations.  There are ways to maintain this properly but I won't go into it here.

If you are not using Visual Studio, please disregard my answer.

Comment: Hurray to that 'hurry' way!   Never read through all the pragma's.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio.
An example of function call is :
void SubScribL1Quotes( char * psymbol,BOOL bSubScrib);
and its response is :
virtual int OnLv2Quote(st_L2Quote *pst);
How do I make to get this response?
Thank you.

Comment: That is very mysterious...  If it was using the Windows message loop, it would at least take a `HWND`, I'd think.  Are you overlooking something?  For instance, is there an event callback function you can set in the API?  Or, does the API create objects?  I see the 'response' is a virtual function.  Presumably something you can override...

Comment: In the API it says:
The PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) function should be put in you message loop. 
If you are using the MFC, put it in your CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage() function.
I am not using MFC, but I don't see any CWinApp class in Win32 Form Project...

Comment: Have a look at this: http://voidnish.wordpress.com/2004/06/21/pretranslatemessage-equivalent-in-a-non-mfc-win32-app/

Comment: This message loop while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) I see in the pure win32 api applications. However in windows form application, I do not see this kind of message loops. How do I make it work in Windows Form project? Or such a thing is impossible?

Comment: Now you're straying into unfamiliar territory for me.  I have never used Windows Forms, sorry.  If this question stagnates, feel free to ask a new question specifically about this.  I would suggest posting more information about the API you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link the project with dll files, you could link your project with lib files, you could add lib file names in your project settings dialog (linker)

Or, you add this to your code

```
#pragma comment(lib,"xxxx.lib")
```

Dll files will be loaded at run-time.

For message loop, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx

Or this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx#modeless_box